# Enable Spring DevTools live reload in Netbeans

Tags: spring, netbeans, spring-boot-devtools

I am struggling with the alleged live-reload functionality of Spring DevTools (in Netbeans).

I have it included in my dependencies: `developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'`

When I run my application, it's showing all the signs that it's included and doing what it's supposed to:

`[  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729`

But changes are not being picked up; the application is not being automatically restarted.

There's clearly some other configuration needed, whether in the application itself or in Netbeans, but I can find no reference to such. What do I need set (working entirely from the IDE) for this functionality to work?